# c# Telegram Bot выполнение длительной задачи

Tags: c#, telegram-bot, task

Здравствуйте у меня есть метод в телеграмм боте, который выполняет свои задачи длительное время, так как телеграмм не может получить ответ от бота, он шлёт новый запрос. Я сделал синхронный вызов, чтобы бот возвращал ответ серверу телеграмм, а сам продолжал свою задачу.
Но по завершению работы в базу данных он не сохраняет данные.
Вот пример кода

```
public async Task<IActionResult> BotStart([FromBody] Update update)
{
    CultureInfo.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US");
    await SaveServiceModel();
    TelegramBotClient client = new(BotConfig.Token);
    if (update.Message != null && update.Message?.Text != null && update.Message.Type == Telegram.Bot.Types.Enums.MessageType.Text)
    {
        // UpdateMessage updateMessage = new(db, update, client, update.Message!.Chat.Id!);
        //await updateMessage.Run();
        if (update.Message.Text == "test")
            Test(db, update, client);
    }
    if (update.CallbackQuery != null)
    {
       // UpdateCallbackQuery updateCallback = new(db, update, client, update.CallbackQuery.From.Id);
       // await updateCallback.Run();
      }
        return Ok();
}
async Task Test(DataContext db, Update update, ITelegramBotClient client)
{
    var user  = db.User.FirstOrDefault(x => x.ID == update.Message.Chat.Id);
    if (user.ReuseCode == true)
    {
        await client.SendTextMessageAsync(user.ID, "Обработка еще не завершена, дождитесь завершения");
        return;
    }
    user.ReuseCode = true;
    lock (this)
        db.SaveChanges();
    int wait = 120;
    int delay = 1000;
    int count = 0;
    await client.SendTextMessageAsync(user.ID, "Обработка запущена");
    while (count <= wait)
    {
        count++;
        await Task.Delay(delay);
    }
    await client.SendTextMessageAsync(user.ID, "Обработка завершена");
    user.ReuseCode = false;
    lock (this)
        db.SaveChanges(); // Не сохраняет user.ReuseCode = false; значение остаётся true
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Это что такое интересное может выполняться 2 минуты? `async void` использовать нельзя, либо весь код внутри надо обернуть в try-catch и обрабатывать исключения. Вероятно у вас исключение, вы просто его не видите.

Comment: @aepot изменил на async Task. У меня метод работает долго так как идёт обработка данных и работа с другим сервером.

Comment: Если `async Task`, тогда где `await`? В противном случае не ожидаемый `Task` все равно что `void`. Ловите исключения, `void` можно оставить при условии что все тсключения будут обработаны.

Comment: @aepot мне нужно синхронное выполнение чтобы на запрос бота я вернул ответ и бот выполнял свою задачу дальше. Если я напишу await Test, то смотрите скрин в  вопросе, я его обновил

Comment: @aepot то есть если я напишу await то телеграм отправит мне 3 запроса и метод будет вызван повторно

Comment: Мне еще разок про обработку исключений написать? Не надо Task, если нет await, это не имеет никакого смысла.

Comment: @aepot Ошибок при выполнение нет. Я бы увидел их в ngrok

Comment: Не увидели бы..

Comment: @aepot написал try catch сейчас запущу, проверю.

Comment: @aepot вы были правы
Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances.
Object name: 'DataContext'.

Comment: @aepot а как он может быть удален сборщиком мусора если я передал его параметром в этот метод?

Comment: Он диспозится после того как вы вернули ответ из метода. Сервер же не знает о том, что вы хотите его дальше использовать. Найдите другой способ найти контекст. После возврата ответа из метода полученный контекст использовать нельзя.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`async Task` можно использовать только так

```
async Task MethodAsync()
{
    // async операции
}
```

```
await MethodAsync();
```

либо

```
Task t = MethodASync();
```

и где-нибудь потом

```
await t;
```

Что касается неожидаемых методов типа "запустил и забыл", то в них нужно отдельно обрабатывать все исключения, в противном случае вы их не увидите, либо крашнете приложение без возможности перехватить исключение (поведение зависит от типа контекста синхронизации)

```
async void FireAndForget()
{
    try
    {
        // async операции
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Log(ex); // залогировать или вывести исключение
    }
}
```

Некоторые разработчики делают логирующее расширение

```
public static class TaskExtensions
{
    public static async void FireAndForget(this Task task)
    {
        try
        {
            await task;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log(ex); // залогировать или вывести исключение
        }
    }
}
```

А потом вызывают вот так

```
MethodAsync().FireAndForget();
```

---

> `Cannot access a disposed context instance. A common cause of this error is disposing a context instance that was resolved from dependency injection and then later trying to use the same context instance elsewhere in your application. This may occur if you are calling 'Dispose' on the context instance, or wrapping it in a using statement. If you are using dependency injection, you should let the dependency injection container take care of disposing context instances. Object name: 'DataContext'.`

`DataContext` нельзя использовать после того как выполнен возврат из контроллера. Найдите другой источник подключения к контексту БД, который будет жить столько сколько вам нужно.

Comment: благодарю, узнал сегодня что то новое, теперь всё работает)

Comment: public async void ServiceReadySms(string Number, string SelectService, int CodeCounter = 0) 
А что делать если метод все равно ожидается? Всё приложение написано на методах Task, вызвав этот метод, поставив брейкпоинты и try catch я вижу что вызов метода дальше этого не происходит, то есть он ждёт выполнения метода, можно как то запустить  Task? код https://pastebin.com/8GgrRgbV

Comment: Сделал такой вызов
Task.Run(() => { ServiceReadySms(Number, Actvatio, SelectService); });
Работает без ожидания

Comment: @xellan вы забыли о чем я писал, Task надо ожидать, Task.Run возвращает Task. Надо либо `await Task.Run(...)` либо как я выше показывал. Иначе будет с исключениями то же самое.

Comment: я помню это, но в случае с void с примера кода это не работает, метод ожидается и тг повторно шлет запросы и код запускается заного..  Исключений нет кстати, метод с Task,Run отрабатывает как надо. И я не могу использовать  await, для этого метода ибо тг шлет новые запросы если не получил ответ